# How to delete same files from a folder that has slightly different names in python?

Tags: python, file, operating-system, glob

I have a folder that has wav files. It has filename.wav and filename.WAV.wav for every wav file.

For example an audio file is saved as audio.wav and audio.WAV.wav. I want to remove these repeatingnames. I know i can do it using glob and os.remove. However, how do I select folders only with a specific name?

```
import os, glob
for filename in glob.glob("thepath/.WAV*"):
os.remove(filename)
```

I know this wrong as names of the audio files are not being considered. I was thinking somehow to chose 'path/(filenamedoesntmatter)(.WAV) . How do I select this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
import os, glob
for filename in glob.glob("thepath/*.WAV*"):
    os.remove(filename)
```

You needed to add an asterisk (*) befor the `.WAV*`, so that it catches any files that have `.WAV` in the name, not just any files that have `.WAV*` at the *beginning*.

Comment: Thank you! Appreciate the help ;)

Comment: No problem! Could you maybe accept the answer, so that others know that the question has been satisfacotrily answered, and so that I get reps for a good anwer ;-)?